# I have a webrtc based screen sharing for cross domain . Its running perfectly in web but when i convert it to electron it stops working

Tags: node.js, webrtc, electron

i have attached the github link 
https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/blob/master/demos/Cross-Domain-Screen-Capturing.html

So from this i'm able to share the screen in chrome. I converted it to electron app. But soon after clicking open room or join room my electron app freezes. But there is no error, i viewed in console no error is there and all steps are getting printed as it does like in chrome window. But screen sharing doesnt open.

Answer (score 2):

electron does not have a built-in window picker, you need to bring your own. [This sample app](https://github.com/hokein/electron-sample-apps/tree/master/desktop-capture) shows how.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply.i have one more doubt, I have used a chrome extension in this web app. So will that work in electron or should I do something else in electron for the chrome extension.

Comment: you don't need the extension as the electron apis does the job the chrome extension does -- returning a chromeMediaSourceId to feed into getUserMedia

Comment: Hi thanks a lot. My electron app is now working fine with your help!. Thanks a lot:)